# Instance of SqlCeConnection takes too long

Tags: database, connection, sql-server-ce

When I create a new instance of `SqlCeConnection` it takes too long to create.

```
connection = new SqlCeConnection ();
```

This line in my program takes about 30 seconds to complete. This started happening to me recently, so when I run the program in another system it does it instantly.

I have added a reference to the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` of the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0, and I have tried doing the local reference, and it does not help either. I would like to know why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be certificate or registry key issue, see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for answering ErikEj, but coincidentally this morning when I tried the program, it started super fast, I have no idea why that can change overnight. I thought maybe Invalid Internet Proxy configuration could be the problem, but in the blog you say what happens when the first call is made to .Open () and it takes me a while when I create a new instance of SqlCeConnection